# How to add simple feedback to an image link?

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

I'm making a simple static app with jQuery Mobile. I'm using images for links to other pages, but am realizing that this leaves the user with no visual feedback. Is there a way (preferably with CSS) I could add a little bit of visual feedback when a link is tapped?

Comment: Yes, you can add a border to the image, Use CSS3 filters to change the image. All sorts. What have you tried?

Comment: I didn't know about filters! I'm going to play around with them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `border` or `box-shadow` to your image while it's state is **focus** or **active**.

For example:

```css
.image{
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #777;
  border: 1px solid #222;
}

.image:focus, .image:active{
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<a href="www.google.com" target="_blank"><div class="image"></div></a>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I didn't realize those pseudo-classes worked with elements besides `<a>`